# React Native: Function Undefined

Tags: react-native, undefined, react-native-ios

I am building an app in react native and keep getting an error with a function being defined and cannot seem to figure out how to fix it.

This is the portion of the code that causes the error. It is meant to fetch data from an api using `redux` and `redux-thunk` to do it.

```py
    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.fetchData(
        V.sprintf(
          "http://timetree.igem.temple.edu/api/pairwise/%s/%s",
          this.state.taxonA,
          this.state.taxonB
        )
      );
    }
```

here is the `fetchData` function that the component uses it is located in an actions folder.

```
export const fetchData = url => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchingRequest());
    try {
     let response = await fetch(url);
     let json = response.json();
     dispatch(fetchingSuccess(json));
    } catch(error){
       dispatch(fetchingFailure(error));
    }
  }
};
```

here is how I try to pass it to the component

```
SearchScreen.propTypes = {
  fetchData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  response: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

Comment: Is it `this.props.fetchData` which is undefined ? How do you pass it to your component ?

Comment: I  used `PropTypes` and declared it as a prop and then called it to the app. I have added it to the the original question above.

Comment: with `propTypes` you're not passing anything, you're testing the type of your props. What exactly do you have in console ?

Comment: You should import your action and pass it to `connect` so it gets passed as a component prop. Do you want me to develop this in an answer ?

Comment: Thank you, the function was not passed through `connect` is what the problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I said in comments with `propTypes` you're not passing anything, you're testing the type of your props. You should import your function and pass it to `connect`.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchData } from '../actions';

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchData })(App);
```

Answer (score -1):

the propType define only the types, not the actual value.
if you export the function 
`export const fetchData`
just import it from your component file, and use it:

```
fetchData(
    V.sprintf(
      "http://timetree.igem.temple.edu/api/pairwise/%s/%s",
      this.state.taxonA,
      this.state.taxonB
    )
  );
```

without "this.props".

Comment: As the function is an action creator it should should be passed as a prop through `connect`

Comment: well the    connect wasn't mentioned at all. importing the exported function will solve the issue.